# base table for dropdown list

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to create a dropdown which loads data from database. I want to create dropdown with key and data as `ID` and `BookName` from `books` table. I followed the tutorial from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_cMkETK330

Steps I've followed.

```
//created model
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AppDropdown extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'books';
}
```

then created provider

```
//created provider
<?php
namespace App\Providers;
use App\AppDropdown; // write model name here 
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class DynamicDDServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('*',function($view){
            $view->with('arrayname', AppDropdown::all());
        });
    }

}
```

then registered the provider in `config/app.php` as `App\Providers\DynamicDDServiceProvider::class`

now in my view page ,

```
<select name="sel_bookID" id="sel_bookID" >
                                    @foreach ($arrayname as $data)                                       
                                        <option value="{{ $data->id }}">{{ $data->BookID }}</option>                                                      
                                    @endforeach
 </select>
```

But I am getting error as ::

```
 Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S02)
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'lsapp.app_dropdowns' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `app_dropdowns`)
```

How does the SQL query creating `app_dropdowns` as table? In model, I've mentioned the table name as `books`.

Comment: Have you a Book model ?

Comment: @Maraboc  not Book its `books` table. thank you.

Comment: This looks fine. Are you sure you don't have any typo's in your actual code?

Comment: Have you tried running `composer dump-autoload` or `php artisan clear-compiled` in the terminal?

Comment: @Jerodev and @Maraboc My model name is `AppDropdown.php`. Is this creating the problem?

Comment: I already have model `Book.php`,when I mentioned Book in provider class it worked. Thank You!!!

Comment: That's why i asked :)

Comment: It should still work since the `$table` property was set correct on the `AppDropdown` model.

Comment: @trommelaap I think the problem is that the Book model point to the books table so the override of the table will not work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need to create provider simply create a model called "Book.php" then fetch all data in your controller using model like Book::all(); and pass it to the view.Now in view use for loop and display the data

in controller

```
use App\Book; //import model 
 $books  = Book::all(); 
 return view('viewName',compact('books')); //compact method is used to 
                                            pass data in view.
```

in View file

```
<select class="form-control" id="select">
        @foreach($books as $book)
        <option>{{$book->id}}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: I already have model named `Book.php`. Please show how can I fetch the data in controller using `Book::all()`. Thank You!